# How to add an eventlistener to a simple google map on an HTML-File

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, addeventlistener

I have the following google map on my simple html file that I got from https://1map.com/map-embed.

```
<div id="wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3" >
        <div id="map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3" style="border-style: solid"></div>

<script>
     (function () {
        var setting = {"height":512,"width":803,"zoom":11,"queryString":"Hagen, Germany","place_id":"ChIJ2yg81387uUcR1jbZgSbWYEM","satellite":false,"centerCoord":[51.341818779747406,7.487431549999997],"cid":"0x4360d62681d936d6","cityUrl":"/germany/hagen-13223","id":"map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3","embed_id":"101027"};
        var d = document;
        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = 'https://1map.com/js/script-for-user.js?embed_id=101027';
        s.async = true;
        s.onload = function (e) {
          window.OneMap.initMap(setting)
        };
        var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        to.parentNode.insertBefore(s, to);
      })();
</script>

<a href="https://1map.com/map-embed?embed_id=101027">1map.com</a></div>
```

I am trying to add eventlisteners for mouse events such as clicks and and hover over etc for this map and its elements, e.g. the `+` and `-` icons for zooming in and out. My problem is that I can't find any element on the above code that I could add an onclick listener to by using `document.getElementById()`. I can add eventlisteners to the divs with the IDs `wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3` and `map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3`. But the listeners for these divs don't  react to clicks or hovering on the map so they are useless. I am new to HTML and javascript and still don't understand many concepts including what is going on in the above code. Is there a way to manipulate this code and listen to mouse events related to the google map without having to use some google APIs?

Comment: That's a route planner. If you want fully interactive maps from google, use [google.maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: Why do you think you can add mouse clicks on the map or markers (other than directly on the map div)?  It looks like it is creating a (free) google embedded map.  Those can't be modified the way you want.  Look at the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: @geocodezip, l don't think that. Rather, l don't know that and I was asking if that's possible. Also I didn't want to use google APIs and was looking for a workaround to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: You have an iframe embeded in your page via the embed code. The content of the iframe a hosted by google and are not exposed to the parent DOM. You **can not** target them.